# Show custom message if record does not exist in database php

Tags: php, database, message, record

Is it possible to display a custom error message if a record doesn't exist in the database?

For example, this page exists as a record in the database:

```
testpage.php?recordID=123456
```

whereas this record does not:

```
testpage.php?recordID=857389
```

Comment: Can you post the contents of `testpage.php`?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to check the number of rows returned using [mysql_num_rows()](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysql_num_rows.asp). If a record exists, `mysql_num_rows` will return 1 or greater (the number of rows that match the query).

You may also want to check first if the query actually ran, or if it encountered an error with your sql. It will detail the errors in [mysql_error()](http://www.w3schools.com/PHP/func_mysql_error.asp).

```
$query = mysql_query($example_sql);

if (!$query = mysql_query($example_sql))
{
    trigger_error(' Mysql_error: ' . mysql_error() . " SQL: " . $example_sql, E_USER_WARNING); //Outputs the error to your error log
    echo "There was an error contacting the database.";
}
else if (mysql_num_rows($query) <= 0)
{
   echo "That record does not exist.";
}
else
{
    //Query returned 1 or more rows, output as normal
}
```

Comment: What's the point in using `__FILE__` and `__LINE__` constants with trigger_error()?

Comment: So you know exactly what file and line the error came from, so you can go back and view where it is in your code. I also show the SQL that caused the error, so you can see what the variables had passed, incase they are the reason for the error.

Comment: Ever tried this code yourself? May I see the example error message produced by it?

Comment: @YourCommonSense `[Mon Mar 19 11:03:22 2012] [error] [client <ip address>] PHP Warning:  File: <full path to the file causing error>.php Line: 1577 Mysql_error: Unknown column 'examplefield' in 'field list' SQL: <error sql> in <full path to the file causing error>.php on line 1577, referer: <referrer file>`

Comment: So, you have the file and the line doubled. Then what's the point in using `__FILE__` and `__LINE__` constants with trigger_error()?

Comment: @YourCommonSense I see that now, thanks. Not sure why I originally added it, and I just never noticed the double.

Comment: may be you have used `log_error()` at first but eventually switched to `trigger_error()` with all the code inside?

Answer (score 0):

you will need to check how many results are returned with that record id:

```
<?php

$recordID = $_GET['recordID'];

$sqldb = /*create database connection here*/

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE id = " . $recordID, $sqldb);
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

if($num_rows > 0)
{
  echo "record exists with id " . $recordID;
}else
{
  echo "record doesn't exist with id " . $recordID;
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to display a custom error message if a record doesn't exist in the database?

Yes.

Usually a page that receives a variable like this, consists of the code which queries a database. And get some result.

It is not forbidden to check such a result with a conditional operator and show whatever message (which most likely have to be an HTTP 404 response).

Answer (score -3):

you could count the rows, `mysql_num_rows`, this would then allow you to find if the ID exists, 1 row = exists, 0 rows = doesn't exist.

```
if (mysql_num_rows($query) < 1) {

    print "This record does not exist);

}
```

Comment: or  `if (mysql_numrows($query) > 0){`

Comment: A query which has no results is NOT a failure. It's a perfectly valid result and you do NOT get a boolean false as a result.